# Directory listing for sub-folders in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket to upload files in the following path syntax:

```
arn:aws:s3:::XXX/{generated string}/logs/{file}
```

I require the bucket's root listing to be private and for a directory listing of each of the logs folders to be public.

The generated folder names are dynamically created so it would not be plausible to manually make each folder public.

I have attempted to use the S3 policy generator, to generate the following policy:

```
{
  "Id": "PolicyID",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ExampleStatement",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListObjects"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::XXX",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "s3:prefix": "*/logs"
        }
      },
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, upon attempting to save this policy AWS throws a "policy has invalid action" error.

How can I create a policy to fit these requirements?

Comment: Try `s3:ListBucket` rather than `s3:ListObjects`.

Comment: Using s3:ListBucket does not give the intended behaviour.

VIsiting "*/logs" gives the error "NoSuchKey".
Visiting "*/logs/" gives the error "AccessDenied".

Comment: Your policy condition should probably be `"*/logs*"` to allow the request.